# Convert from pixel to cm with camera matrix and distance, opencv function

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box, measure

Is there any opencv function to convert pixel to cm?

I have a bounding box in pixel and want to know the size of my object in cm.
I have already done a camera calibration to get my camera-matrix with the focal *f*<sub>x</sub> and *f*<sub>y</sub>.

So normally the formula for my vector of one point is:

*p*<sub>x</sub>[cm]= *z*/*f*<sub>x</sub> (*u* - *c*<sub>x</sub>) and *p*<sub>y</sub>[cm]= *z*/*f*<sub>y</sub> (*v* - *c*<sub>y</sub>)

where *z* is the distance in cm from camera to object, *f* the focal length, *u* and *v* is the point in pixel and *c* is the camera main point (middle point of the picture).

I get the distance to my object from a sensor.

Of course I can do this for all my box points and do some trigonometry to find the length and hight of my object in cm.

But I was wondering if there is already some opencv or other function for this. Unfortunately I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an object and you know its size, maybe look at this [post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) then this [post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/04/measuring-distance-between-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/).

Some people also use the Aruco Marker as a known object since OpenCV has an Aruco detector :

```
# Load Aruco detector
parameters = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.Dictionary_get(cv2.aruco.DICT_5X5_50)

# Get Aruco marker
corners, _, _ = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(img, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)

# Draw polygon around the marker
int_corners = np.int0(corners)
cv2.polylines(img, int_corners, True, (0, 255, 0), 5)
```

source : [pysource](https://pysource.com/2021/05/28/measure-size-of-an-object-with-opencv-aruco-marker-and-python/)

In case you don't know the size of any object, you need to [calibrate your camera](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html)

Comment: I dont want to use a reference object lik Aruco Marker. As I said before, I already calbibrated the camera, but what to do next to find the object szie in cm?